# Google Drive initiate download of a public file on your website

Tags: embed, google-drive-api

I have found ways to embed a public folder from Google Drive on my website. This is done like this:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDERID#list"></iframe>
```

You can also link directly to a public file like this:

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILEID
```

The Google Drive embedded view shows the list of files in that public folder. Clicking on the file you are redirected to Google Drive file preview page, from where you can download then file. I would like to skip this step and allow visitors to my page to click on a file and initiate this download immediately. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Go to where your file is located on Google Drive click on File - top left corner.
Then "right click" on the option named -Download- this will give you the direct link to your file so that you can use it as the download link.

Comment: Is there a better solution where you can really provide the download functionality to the end-user and not having to manually create the download link and embed it in your site, but just the iFrame.